# Can burning mobs set trees on fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've built a tree house, it's going well, but I'm worried that mobs burning at dawn could bring the whole thing down in minutes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it's not.

It would be a pretty stupid feature actually since zombies and skeletons burn upon sunrise. You wouldn't have a single tree on the map after day or two. :-D

Comment: You say stupid, I say hilarious. :D

Answer (score -1):

I started to build Yggdrasil, the world tree, and invested hundreds and hundreds of wood (and many hours). I also went through and made sure there was no lava within 2 blocks of the wood.

AND YET...

It burned to the ground. It was in a shaft that let sunlight in so I'm wondering if it IS possible for burning mobs to set fire to things... I shall build a trap to test it!

Of course, maybe I just missed some lava. I was pretty thorough, though.

UPDATE: At least, according to this walkthrough, they can: http://pc.mmgn.com/Walkthroughs/Minecraft-FAQ

Comment: That "walkthrough" was last updated January 20th... that's _ancient._

Comment: When did you start building the tree? If you were working on it during 1.5 or greater when lightning was introduced, that would most likely be the cause. Lightning can lit any burnable blocks on fire and the rain doesn't put it out, or at least it didn't when storms first came out.